# Access multiple objects and arrays in JSON in jQuery $.each

Tags: jquery, json

Access multiple objects/arrays in JSON in jQuery $.each

```
[{"APMUserObj":[{"APMUserId":6,"APMUserName":"sadasd asdasd"},
{"APMUserId":7,"APMUserName":"DWDWD DSDAWDASDASD"},
{"APMUserId":8,"APMUserName":"EWRWER EWRWER"},
{"APMUserId":9,"APMUserName":"tert rtert"},
{"APMUserId":11,"APMUserName":"vsfvd fgdfgdfhyrhr"},}],"CCUserObj":
[],"VoaUserObj":[]}
```

How to embedd only ApmUserobj it in for each?

Answer (score 0):

```
    var obj = {"APMUserObj":[
        {"APMUserId":6,"APMUserName":"sadasd asdasd"}
       ,{"APMUserId":7,"APMUserName":"DWDWD DSDAWDASDASD"}
       ,{"APMUserId":8,"APMUserName":"EWRWER EWRWER"}
       ,{"APMUserId":9,"APMUserName":"tert rtert"}
       ,{"APMUserId":11,"APMUserName":"vsfvd fgdfgdfhyrhr"}]
       ,"CCUserObj":[]
       ,"VoaUserObj":[]
    };
    $(obj.APMUserObj).each(function(){
        console.log(this.APMUserName);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tvww03a8/